# Apple Script - to choose color displays a buttonless headless color wheel Color Picker

Tags: applescript

I used the information on this post to create a Color Picker on my mac to replace the digital color meter app.

http://www.macosxtips.co.uk/index_files/replace-digitalcolor-meter-in-lion.php

But after I did that, I get a color picker alright, but the buttons on the top that lets me shift between color wheel, color slider, color palletes, image, hex etc dont appear. They appear only when I run the apple script from the apple script editor. When I save the apple script as an app and run it by double clicking it, I just a get simple color wheel with none of the buttons on the top.

I use Mac OS Lion..

Thanks!

**EDIT: Adding a screenshot :**

[image]

Comment: I'm using Lion and my color wheel displays properly when running the applescript code as an application. Question: if you open TextEdit and show the color wheel by pressing shift-command-c does it display properly? I'm thinking you hid the buttons at the top somehow and thus it's not working properly for you in other applications as well.

Comment: Nope from text edit all the buttons appear. When I run choose color from the apple script editor all the buttons appear. Only when I compile the script as an app the buttons disappear! Not sure what I am doing wrong..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wanted colors as a hex value so I also looked to applescript for a solution. Check out [this blog post](https://techblog.willshouse.com/2011/12/29/colorpicker-applescript-for-mac-os-x/) for a complete example, and also a downloadable applescript application (with a nice icon) that you can customize to your needs. I have tested it with OS X Lion and it seems to work fine.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks.. but it also has the same problem. I have edited my question to add a screenshot this time. Where is the top portion of the panel disappearing?

Comment: @sethu - do you have a ~/Library/Preferences/applet.plist file? if so, try moving that to your desktop (to keep it from being used), or if you have a plist editing tool, change the value of NSColorPanelToolbarIsShown.modal in that file from 0 to 1 and then it should start showing the bar again.

Comment: Thanks that worked!.. Finally after so many months I have got this working.. I had to change NSToolbar Configuration->TB is Shown from 0 to 1.